# How do you measure the energy consumption of an EC2 instance ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have asked to give a report on the energy consumption of an m5.12xlarge instance. I am wondering how to come up with a factual and approximate number here. Anyone had come across this issue anywhere ?

Comment: m5.12xlarge is using  28 cores 2.5 GHz Intel Xeon Platinum 8175. AWS count each core as one vCPU ,  and m5.12xlarge is given 48 cores. So  you can safely assume that 2 Intel Xeon Platinum 8175 is used. And the CPU top power draw is 165 W, time the number by 2 . In addition, you must also calculate the RAM power consumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important concept of the Cloud is that server utilization is often much higher.

In a normal data center, a server is running 24 hours but is only *used* a few hours a day, and often not fully utilized in those hours.

In the Cloud, when an instance is not required it can be turned off, which means that the capacity is available for somebody else to use. Instance size can also be selected so that it is big enough for the desired workload, without having to get large servers for a potential *future* workload.

Thus, there is **significantly less wastage in the cloud** compared to on-premises servers. I mention this because somebody has presumably asked you to measure the environmental impact of a choice of computing infrastructure, and it's not really accurate to directly compare on-premises vs the Cloud since on-premises is typically over-provisioned and under-utilized.

A good article on this topic: [Cloud Computing, Server Utilization, & the Environment | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloud-computing-server-utilization-the-environment/)

Comment: I'm not clear how this answers the actual question.